# Validation for a Divide by Zero in PHP

Tags: php, html, validation, calculator

I'm making a simple Calculator in PHP and want to create validation for a divide by 0.

At the moment when a user divides by zero, PHP issues the warning **Warning: Division by zero in**

I know I need to check if y == 0 if the user is doing division, but I'm unsure where to put it in my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>PHP Calculator</title>
   </head>

   <body>

      <h3>PHP Calculator (Version 6)</h3>
      <p>Add, subtract, divide or multiply and output the result</p>
     
       <form method="get" action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <input type = "number" name = "x" placeholder = "0" required>
            <select name = "operator">
                <option>None</option>
                <option>+</option>
                <option>-</option>
                <option>*</option>
                <option>/</option>
            </select>
            <input type = "number" name = "y" placeholder = "0" required>
            
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate"/>
        </form>
       
        <p>The answer is: </p>
       
    <?php 
       if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
           $x = $_GET['x'];
           $y = $_GET['y'];
           $operator = $_GET['operator'];
           
      
       switch ($operator) {
           case "+":
               echo $x + $y;
               break;
           case "-":
               echo $x - $y;
               break;
           case "*":
               echo $x * $y;
               break;
           case "/":
               echo $x / $y;
               break;
           default:
               echo "You should to select a method!";
               break;
       }

     }
  
    ?>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably makes sense to put it in the `case "/":` area I'd have thought?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would put it in the switch statement in division case,

```
 case "/":
           echo $y==0 ? 'Illegal divisor' : ($x / $y);
           break;
```

This will ensure readability of your code.

If you're not familiar with the ternary operator here's the syntax:

> {condtion} ? {true statement} : {false statement}